# Add flags on Makefile compilation only if a parameter is given

Tags: c, makefile

I would like to know how the CFLAGS variable could be removed from the compilation and added when a parameter is given to the Makefile like "make cflags" without having to duplicate the compilation.

Here is a part of my Makefile :

```
EXE =   $(PATH_EXE)/COLLECTEUR

all:    ${EXE}

clean:
    rm -f ${PATH_OBJ}/*.o
    rm -f ${PATH_EXE}/*

clean_bin:
    rm -f ${PATH_EXE}/*

link:
    rm -f ${PATH_EXE}/*


$(PATH_EXE)/COLLECTEUR: $(PATH_OBJ)/Test.o $(OBJS) 
    ${LD}  ${CFLAGS} ${OBJS} $(PATH_OBJ)/Test.o  ${LDFLAGS}  -o $@


$(PATH_OBJ)/%.o  : %.c
    ${CC}  ${CFLAGS} $< -o $@
```

Comment: Please show both "makefile versions" you want to use/select with the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general trick in make is to use a feature known as a [target specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), which allows you to set or append to variables if a specific target is given, like so:

```
cflags: CFLAGS+=-Wall -Werror

cflags: all
```

What this says is for the target `cflags` append `-Wall -Werror` to the cflags, and the following line says that the `cflags` target depends on the `all` target.

Now, I did notice some errors in your compilation options.

The final link line `${LD}` will invoke `ld`, which doesn't take `${CFLAGS}` by default, you're probably better off using the compiler driver there as well (replace the `${LD}` with `${CC}`).

The compilation line for `$(PATH_OBJ)/%.o` files compiles *and links* the files, because it's missing the `-c` option, which instructs the compiler to compile only, and not to link.

Comment: Great ! Thank you for the tips as well !

Comment: Just to clarify this is a feature of GNU make called _target-specific variables_ : https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html